# Could not find artifact org.codehaus.mojo:mojo-sandbox:pom:3-SNAPSHOT in codehaus snapshot

Tags: maven

Does anyone know why I get this error even if I forced the update (-U) ?

This error came about when I tried to build this POM.xml.

[POM.XML]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>wrox</groupId>
    <artifactId>pixweb</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1</version>
    <description></description>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>New central Maven repo</id>
            <url>http://repo2.maven.org/maven2/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>codehaus snapshot</id>
            <url>http://snapshots.repository.codehaus.org</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
        <testSourceDirectory>src/test/java</testSourceDirectory>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
                <directory>src/main/java</directory>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*.properties</include>
                    <include>**/*.xml</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <testResources>
            <testResource>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
                <directory>src/test/java</directory>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </testResource>
            <testResource>
                <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
            </testResource>
        </testResources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.5</source>
                    <target>1.5</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <wtpversion>1.0</wtpversion>
                    <additionalBuildcommands>
                        <buildcommand>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springbuilder</buildcommand>
                    </additionalBuildcommands>
                    <additionalProjectnatures>
                        <projectnature>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springnature</projectnature>
                    </additionalProjectnatures>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>xfire-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>wsgen</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <package>com.wrox.webservice.emailvalidation.client</package>
                    <overwrtite>true</overwrtite>
                    <generateServerStubs>false</generateServerStubs>
                    <forceBare>false</forceBare>
                    <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources</outputDirectory>
                    <wsdls>
                        <wsdl>http://ws.xwebservices.com/XWebEmailValidation/V2/XWebEmailValidation.wsdl</wsdl>
                    </wsdls>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
            <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
            <version>${taglibs-standard-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>${jstl-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>${servlet-api-version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>${commons-fileupload-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.1.ga</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
                    <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>geronimo-spec</groupId>
            <artifactId>geronimo-spec-jta</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1B-rc4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webflow</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-webflow-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-mock</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jms</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>hsqldb</groupId>
            <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
            <version>${hsqldb-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.directwebremoting</groupId>
            <artifactId>dwr</artifactId>
            <version>${dwr-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>${junit-version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
            <version>${commons-lang-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.lowagie</groupId>
            <artifactId>itext</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>rome</groupId>
            <artifactId>rome</artifactId>
            <version>0.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.xfire</groupId>
            <artifactId>xfire-aegis</artifactId>
            <version>${xfire-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.xfire</groupId>
            <artifactId>xfire-core</artifactId>
            <version>${xfire-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.xfire</groupId>
            <artifactId>xfire-spring</artifactId>
            <version>${xfire-version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>spring</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.xfire</groupId>
            <artifactId>xfire-java5</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.xfire</groupId>
            <artifactId>xfire-generator</artifactId>
            <version>${xfire-version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>spring</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.xfire</groupId>
            <artifactId>xfire-jaxws</artifactId>
            <version>${xfire-version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
            <artifactId>activemq-core</artifactId>
            <version>${activemq-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>fm.void.jetm</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetm</artifactId>
            <version>${jetm-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>fm.void.jetm</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetm-optional</artifactId>
            <version>${jetm-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>cglib</groupId>
            <artifactId>cglib-nodep</artifactId>
            <version>${cglib-version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <properties>
        <activemq-version>4.1.1</activemq-version>
        <spring-webflow-version>1.0.3</spring-webflow-version>
        <spring-version>2.0.5</spring-version>
        <junit-version>3.8.2</junit-version>
        <commons-lang-version>2.1</commons-lang-version>
        <dwr-version>2.0.1</dwr-version>
        <jstl-version>1.0</jstl-version>
        <taglibs-standard-version>1.1.1</taglibs-standard-version>
        <hsqldb-version>1.8.0.7</hsqldb-version>
        <servlet-api-version>2.5</servlet-api-version>
        <log4j-version>1.2.14</log4j-version>
        <commons-fileupload-version>1.1.1</commons-fileupload-version>
        <xfire-version>1.2.4</xfire-version>
        <jetm-version>1.2.1</jetm-version>
        <cglib-version>2.1_3</cglib-version>
    </properties>
</project>
```

[ERROR MSG]. Btw, I replaced the http with http1.

[Error Trace here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/13y33EE3KL2aAf7_8c1UpJM7uQ3cCaDIqjPK4I5um3Vw/edit?hl=en_US)

Answer (score 0):

The error comes when maven is trying to download dependencies for [Maven XFire plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/xfire-maven-plugin/).

According to the documentation, the plugin is deprecated. It was last updated in 2006. It is having a `SNAPSHOT` version and may be referring to dependencies which are incorrect/outdated.

Comment: Thanks Raghuram!! How will I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Had same problem. Changing the coordinates of the plugin to:

```
<groupId>org.apache.servicemix.tooling</groupId>
<artifactId>xfire-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>4.0</version>
```

made it work.